# Access collection field in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

How can I access a field in collection in twig

```
$builder
->add('name', 'text', array('required' => false))
->add('email', 'collection', array(
    'type'      => new UsersEmailAddressesType(),
    'allow_add' => true
))
```

`UserEmailAddressesType` has two fields `name` and `email`, how can I access email field in twig ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to access? values, attributes? and for what purpose?

Comment: I want to enter what `input` field so I could set them next to each other

Comment: explain please dont know what you mean by "enter what input field". do you want to add a class , an attribute ? to align them with css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the symfony cookbook there is an example on [how to embed collections in forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). The solution there looks like this (adapted to your form example):

```
<ul>
{% for email in form.email %}
    <li>{{ form_row(email.address) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Since you want to place the inputs next to each other you might want to check whether the loop.index is `odd`, `even` or `divisibleby()` for example like this:

```
{% for email in form.email %}
    {% if loop.index is odd %}
        <li class="float-left">
    {% else %}
        <li class="float-right">
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_row(email.address) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```